# how can I apply borders to the dataset and export it using Import Export XML Library

Tags: vb.net

I'm using [This Excel XML Library from Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22935/A-Very-Easy-to-Use-Excel-XML-Import-Export-Library) to export data using dataset to Excel file. The data is getting exported successfully. But I want to apply styles to that data before exporting it. And I don't know how to do it.

Please help me...

Here's what I have done so far...

```
Dim dt As New DataSet
    Dim flnm As String
    'Dim row, col As Integer
    flnm = Now.Year.ToString + "-" + Now.Month.ToString + "-" + Now.Day.ToString + "-" + Now.Hour.ToString + "-" + Now.Minute.ToString + "-" + Now.Second.ToString + ".xls"
    btnExport.Text = "कृपया प्रतीक्षा करा..."
    btnExport.Enabled = False

    Dim book As New ExcelXmlWorkbook()
    Dim cell As New CellCollection


    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("D:\ATMA")) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\ATMA")
    End If

    dt.Tables.Add(dataset)

    book = ExcelXmlWorkbook.DataSetToWorkbook(dt)

    Dim sheet = book(0)

    Dim row = sheet(0)
    row.Style.Border.LineStyle = Borderline.Continuous
    row.Style.Border.Sides = BorderSides.All

    book.Export("D:\ATMA\" + flnm)

    MessageBox.Show("माहिती यशस्वीरित्या एक्सपोर्ट करण्यात आलेली आहे. फाईल येथे पहा D:\ATMA\" + flnm)

    btnExport.Text = "एक्सपोर्ट करा "
    btnExport.Enabled = True
```

Comment: You can use **Style** to give the border of the Cell. See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22935/A-Very-Easy-to-Use-Excel-XML-Import-Export-Library#premain842722

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Style** to give the border of the Cell. [See documentation here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22935/A-Very-Easy-to-Use-Excel-XML-Import-Export-Library#premain842722)

#### Styles

All cells, rows, and worksheets have styles which can be set individually. **These are `Font`, `Alignment`, `Interior`, `Border`, and `DisplayFormat`.** More information can be found in the documentation about members of the style classes. Changing a worksheet style setting affects all cells in the worksheet. A row setting affects all child cells in the row, and a single cell setting affects, well, that very cell. Example: